# Snakemake rule does not regenerate output after input has changed

Tags: dependencies, snakemake, flags, directed-acyclic-graphs

My Snakemake workflow includes rule compse:

```
rule compose:
input:
    manuscripts=[
        str(a)
        for a in Path(".").glob(f"./{config['series']}_*_*_*/tei/*.xml")
        if not (config["publication"] in str(a))
    ],
    assets=[str(a) for a in Path(".").glob(f"{config['series']}_*/assets/*.*")],
    script=expand("{dir}/other/compose.xsl", dir=config["transform"]),
output:
    touch("composed.flag"),
params:
    publication=config["publication"],
    saxon=config["saxon"],
run:
    SOMECODE (see below)
```

It takes some xml files, images and a script and outputs a flag file that documents that it ran sucessfully. The input files are not generated by another rule but pre-exist the workflow, thus you could say the rule is isolated - it does not depend on others and does not produce output that other rules depend on.

When I call the rule from the cli like `snakemake -p -c1 compose --config workdir="/home/lector/manuscripts/ends-of-humanities/eoh_01_mein_eoh"` it generates the expected output.

When I change one of the inputs, I expect the rule to run again because the timestamp of these inputs is younger than the flag file. However, Snakemake does not run it again and claims:

```
Config file config/config.yaml is extended by additional config specified via the command line.
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).
```

Even if I add the `-f` flag to force rerun it stops without regenerating the output.

If I compare the timestamp of the changed input file with the flag file it is nevertheless true that the input is younger than the output, so why does Snakemake pretend otherwise and refuses to run the rule?

*code of the run: directive:*

```
run:
    # Create publication, tei and assets folder
    (Path(".") / "tei/media/").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    (Path(".") / "assets/").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    # Create dummy docx file
    shell("touch {params.publication}.docx")
    # Copy article assets to volume assets / tei/media (cp without loop causes exception)
    for f in input.assets:
        shell("cp {f} assets/")
    shell("cp -rf assets/* tei/media/")
    # Copy transformation script
    shell("cp -a {input.script} tei/compose.xsl")
    # Generate list of manuscript files in intermediate xml file
    shell("echo '<collection/>' > tei/manuscripts.xml")
    for man in input.manuscripts:
        m = man.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        shell(
            "xmlstarlet ed -L -s '/collection' -t elem -n 'doc' -v '' -i '/collection/doc[last()]' -t attr -n 'href' -v '../{m}/tei/{m}.xml' tei/manuscripts.xml"
        )
    # Transform collection file to final TEI-XML manuscript
    shell(
        "java -jar {params.saxon} -o:tei/{params.publication}.xml tei/manuscripts.xml tei/compose.xsl projectfolder={params.publication}"
    )
    # Clean-Up publication folder
    shell("rm -f tei/manuscripts.xml tei/compose.xsl")
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue and I filed a bug here https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2011 (for the future, try to strip down the example to a minimum)